# Uncaught Error: not an array ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, charts

I am trying to fetch data from SQL server via JSON format into Google charts but I am getting the following error

> <s>Uncaught error: not an array</s> - Resolved. Answer below in EDIT
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/05/how-to-create-google-bar-chart-with-database-data-aspnet.html)

**JS Code** in charts.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 
        <script>
            var chartData; // globar variable for hold chart data
            google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            // Here We will fill chartData

            $(document).ready(function () {
       
                $.ajax({
                    url: "charts.aspx/GetChartData",
                    data: "",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        chartData = data.d;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                    // after complete loading data
                    
                    drawChart();
                });
            });


            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

                var options = {
                    title: "Count",
                    pointSize: 5
                };

                var barChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                barChart.draw(data, options);

            }

 
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

**HTML Code** in charts.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <div id="chart_div" style="width:500px;height:400px">
                <%-- Here Chart Will Load --%>
            </div>

</asp:Content>
```

**C# Code** - charts.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object[] GetChartData()
{
    List<Main> data = new List<Main>();
    //Here MyDatabaseEntities  is our dbContext
    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        data = dc.Mains.ToList();
    }

    var chartData = new object[data.Count + 1];
    chartData[0] = new object[]{
            "Status",
            "status reason"
        };

    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in data)
    {
        j++;

        chartData[j] = new object[]
        {
            i.Incident_Status.ToString(), i.Status_Reason.ToString()
        };

        //chartData[j] = new object[] { i.Year.ToString(), i.Electronics, i.BookAndMedia, i.HomeAndKitchen };
    }
    return chartData;
}
```

**JSON Output**

```
{Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,…}
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
Message :   "Authentication failed."
StackTrace  :  null
```

EDIT -
I tried adding

```
<authorization>
        <allow users="*" /> 
 </authorization>
```

in web.config because I was facing authorization error. But it still didn't help.

EDIT2 -
I added in App_Date/RouteConfig.js

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

This resolved the JSON issue. I am now getting proper response

```
d: [["Status", "status reason"], ["Closed", "No Further Action Required"],…]}
d: [["Status", "status reason"], ["Closed", "No Further Action Required"],…]
```

Still data is not loading.

Comment: `Is there a way to check my JSON output?` Yes, look in the network tab of your browsers developer tools.

Comment: Please post your response JSON

Comment: I've shared the JSON response for GetChartData

Comment: @PirateX I recommend using [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It's a very good javascript library for turning your data into charts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse JSON before passing parameter to function:

```
 function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(chartData));

            var options = {
                title: "Count",
                pointSize: 5
            };

            var barChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            barChart.draw(data, options);

        }
```

**UPDATE:**

It doesn't matter I just did mistake `$.parseJSON` is deprecated. So I changed a bit. But I just changed your javascript function.

**UPDATE 2:**

In your JSCode: `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);`

Fix: `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(chartData));`

Comment: I'm coding in C#, what you have suggested is for PHP. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PirateX the code he posted is javascript... it has nothing to do with c# or PHP

Comment: I tried your code. But it doesn't help honestly, more errors TBH :(